# if a variable is defined in a class extends a trait, how to use it in the trait?

Tags: scala

I have the following code, T1 need to access "a" which is the constructor parameter of Test (extends T1), but compile failed. How to fix it?

```
trait T1 {
  def x=a.length
}
class Test(a:String) extends T1{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. Declare `a` in your trait as an abstract member:

   `trait T1 { def a: String; def x = a.length }
   class Test(val a: String) extends T1`
2. Create a different trait that declares `a`:

   `trait HasA { def a: String }
   trait T1 extends HashA { def x = a.length; }
   class Test(val a: String) extends T1`
3. Require that T1 can only be used by classes that have `a`:

   `trait HasA { def a: String }
   trait T1 { self: HasA => def x = a.length }
   class Test(val a: String) extends HasA with T1`

Answer (score 3):

As I said before in a comment it doesn't make much sense to me, anyway you can use a self type reference to the trait and make the variable accessible using `val`:

```
trait T1 {
  self: Test => // self type reference.

  def x= a.length
}

class Test(val a: String) extends T1{ }
```

In this way though `T1` will be only extendable from `Test` or class which inherits from it.