# why val work but var doesn't in constructor in this case (scala)

Tags: scala

I asked the following question
[if a variable is defined in a class extends a trait, how to use it in the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402938/if-a-variable-is-defined-in-a-class-extends-a-trait-how-to-use-it-in-the-trait)

And one of the answer is as below:

```
trait T1 { def a: String; def x = a.length }
class Test(val a: String) extends T1
```

But if only works:

1. define a in T1 as "def a", if I use "val a" or "var a", then it doesn't work
2. define a in Test as "val a", if I just use "a" which means default to "var a", it also doesn't work.

Why does it happen?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't describe the error you're seeing. *Always* describe the actual error.

Comment: Works for me: `scala> trait T1 { val a: String;  def x = a.length }
defined trait T1
scala> class Test(val a: String) extends T1
defined class Test
scala> new Test("foo").x
res0: Int = 3`

Comment: It doesn't "default to `var a`" - if you write `class Test(a: String)` then that is *not* the same as `class Test(var a: String)`. For case classes it's the same as `val a` but not `var a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"#1" should work, as I mentioned in the comment.
Regarding #2, there two things:

1. `class Test(a: String)` is *not* the same as `class Test(var a: String)` (if anything, it is actually closer to `val` declaration, but isn't the same either, except for case classes). The latter declares `a` as a mutable class member, while the former just makes it an argument to the constructor, not a member of the class at all. For this reason, it fails in your case: you have to override the abstract member `a` of `T1` in order to be able to extend it.
2. `class Test(var a: String)` won't work either. This is because `a` is declared in `T1` as `def`, which makes it immutable. You can override a `def` with a `def` or a `val`, but you cannot override it with a mutable value. If you need it to be mutable in `Test`, you have to declare it as a `var` in `T1` as well.

Comment: `class Test(a: String)` is more like `class Test(private[this] val a: String)`.

Comment: @Dima: you said "This is because a is declared in T1 as def, which makes it immutable", why def is immutable? every time def run, it could return a different object. say : def x=new someObject()

Comment: Well, actually, it looks like I was wrong. Turns out, that, at least, in scala 2.9.3, you *can* override a `def` with a `var`: 

`trait Foo { def x: Int }; class Bar(var x) extends Foo;`

works for me ... I could swear it did not use to, but don't know when the behavior has changed